# remove next td on mouse enter event

Tags: jquery, html

I want to remove the next td of mouseenter of td. But my code remove the first occurrence of mouseenter of td and current mouseover td. my code here. what error in this code?

```
 $(document).on("mouseenter ", "td.content" , function(e) {     
        var ParentTdRemove = $(this).closest('td');         
        if( $(this).hasClass("content")){
            $('#addexpandtd').show();
            var top_pos = $(this).position().top;
            var left_post = $(this).position().left;    
            $('#addexpandtd').css('position', 'absolute');
            top_pos = top_pos-25;
            $('#addexpandtd').css('top',top_pos); 
            $('#addexpandtd').css('left', left_post);

            $(document).on("click", ".removetbletdimg" , function(e ) {
                   ParentTdRemove.remove(); 
                   return false;
            }); 

            $(document).on("click", ".expandtdimg" , function(e ) {  
                if(ParentTdRemove.next('td').is('.addtd')==false){
                    ParentTdRemove.next('td').remove();
                }
            });
       }

}).on('mouseleave',"td.content" , function() {
 $("#addexpandtd").hide();
});
```

My html is

```
<table class="dynmictable">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="ui-droppable ui-sortable content tbledata"></td>
        <td class="ui-droppable ui-sortable content tbledata"></td>
        <td class="ui-droppable ui-sortable content tbledata"></td>
        <td class="addtd"><img src="images/plus_td.png" class="" id="addtditem"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<div id="addexpandtd" style="display: block; position: absolute; top: 232.375px; left: 381.25px;">
    <img src="images/expand.png" class="expandtdimg">
    <img src="images/Close-icon.png" class="removetbletdimg" id="">
</div>
```

Comment: post your html as welll

Comment: is `addexpandtd` the next td... if so are there multiple elments with the same id

Comment: You likely want next() instead of closest which goes UP the dom

Comment: You asked this yesterday and know that people asked for a live demo with html. create a demo in jsfiddle.net that replicates the problem

Comment: Also, there is no respons on yesterday's post

Comment: Put a demo together and I assure you there will be

Comment: Can you put jsfiddle...

Comment: its not working. I'm trying many times. but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`closest` is used to search up on the dom tree and aside nested tables you are not in this case, I think you want the current `td`.

So you can set a class on the current element and use that class to search the current element or its next on the button click.

In this way you can avoid the use of `ParentTdRemove` and you can attach one click handler and don't bind it in every mouseover.

Code:

```
$(document).on("mouseenter ", "td.content", function (e) {    
    if ($(this).hasClass("content")) {
        $('#addexpandtd').show();
        var top_pos = $(this).position().top;
        var left_post = $(this).position().left;
        $('#addexpandtd').css('position', 'absolute');
        top_pos = top_pos - 25;
        $('#addexpandtd').css('top', top_pos);
        $('#addexpandtd').css('left', left_post);

        $('td.content').removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');
    }

}).on('mouseleave', "td.content", function () {
    $(this).removeClass('current');
    $("#addexpandtd").hide();
});

$(document).on("click", ".removetbletdimg", function (e) {
    $('td.content.current').remove();
    return false;
});

$(document).on("click", ".expandtdimg", function (e) {
    if ($('td.content.current').next('td').is('.addtd') == false) {
        $('td.content.current').next('td').remove();
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/f694s1bb/